# Cannot create a Parse account

Tags: parse-platform

I can not find a SignUp Button or a register button on parse. Is it possible new users to register on the site? All I want is to save an android data to a cloud/server with very simple way.

Comment: I don't believe so. If you go to https://www.parse.com/login and click "I don't have a Parse account" on the bottom, it directs you to /signup but you end up on the main page. As you probably know, Parse is closing.

Comment: so we cant create a new accout? and the best related site is firebase? am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, You cannot currently setup a new account with Parse.com. This is because the entire platform offering is being shutdown.

They have however open source a majority of the technology behind the platform.
Visit https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server for how to setup your self-hosted instance of the parse-server.

You can however check out http://firebase.com. Their offering is similar to Parse

Goodluck